# How to switch to GCC44

Tags: macos, gcc, macports

I'm using osx Lion and I installed Gcc44 through macport.

I also selected that version by means of the command

```
sudo port select gcc mp-gcc44
```

Now it is the active version, as reported by the command

```
sudo port select gcc
```

However when I try to install other ports, macport still use the version 4.2 (I think the apple one).

How can I fix it?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The policy of the MacPorts project is for a port to use the default Apple-supplied compiler for a particular release unless there is some demonstrated reason why that port needs something different.  Often those ports will have variants that allow a different MacPorts-provided compiler to be used.  For example, you can [search for ports that have a gcc44 variant](http://www.macports.org/ports.php?by=variant&substr=gcc44).  So, if you wanted to install the gcc44 variant of `atlas`,  you would specify:

```
port install atlas +gcc44
```

That only works for ports that have defined variants.  If you wanted to override the MacPorts defaults for a particular port, you could modify its ports file.  The MacPorts guide documents the fields and their values, for instance, [here](http://guide.macports.org/#reference.phases.configure).  In general, though, you should stick to the defaults used in the MacPorts port file for a port.